# org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown type: T

Tags: java, generics, serialization, avro

I am serializing a big Java object, which has many Java fields with generic type like:

```
Class A<T>
```

I have used  `@AvroSchema("[\"string\"]")` wherever possible , but it is still showing me the error. How do we know for which specific field we are getting this error?

PS: The print stack trace does not help and neither debugging the code.

Comment: Please share complete code and exception

Comment: *"showing me the error"*, *"we are getting this error"* - what error?

Comment: This is still an [open issue][1] with Avro.


  [1]: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1571

Comment: @MonishSen,@luk2303  Sorry , in hurry I missed to post the error , the error is 
Caused by: avro.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown type: T

Comment: is there an update on this problem? I have the same issue, and the only way around it I can find is to alter the code so the object is not generic